# Edit in view page or index.cshtml in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 and Entity framework 6 (Database First) in my application.
I need to update **"value"** field in View page\index.cshtml.
Is it possible to use **@Html.EditorFor** to edit Value field for each Item on single button click?
Here is the code in index.cshtml

```
<table>
 <tr>
        <th>
            Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Value
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>     
    </tr>
     foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.number)                
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.value)
             @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.value) *@       
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
            </td>
  @* <td>
       @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id })      
    </td>*@
</tr>
</table>
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />          
        </div>
</div>
```

On clicking Save button I should update the data in **Value** field for any number of rows.
It's done in Database First so action for Edit,View,Details are included in Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to put everything in a  to post the details to the server, then you can manage the posted elements. You'll post a list of itens. Maybe this will help you: [How can I post a list of items in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321736/how-can-i-post-a-list-of-items-in-mvc)