# Choosing and keeping multiple radio button value inside a table

Tags: sql, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, radio-group

I am using radio button for choosing employee type such as part-time , full-time etc.I could choose only one item according followed table structure.How can i select multiple radio button and keep these inside a table.For instance such as keeping inside an array?

```
+--------------+----------------+
|  EmployeeId  |  EmployeeType  |
+--------------+----------------+
|      2       |       2        |    
+--------------+----------------+
|      3       |       1        |    
+--------------+----------------+


EmployeeTypes : 
0 Part-time
1 Full-time
2 Consultant
3 Trainer
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, radio buttons work by posting different values to the same name - the value of the item selected.

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

However, if you have a table of data, and you need to be able to edit multiple rows at the same time, there will be the need to differentiate between EmployeeType for User 2 and EmployeeType for User 3.  So the radio buttons with various values might now instead post to names such as **EmployeeType_2** and **EmployeeType_3**.

This is essentially what will happen behind the scenes when you try to do code like the following.

[How can I post a list of items in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321736/how-can-i-post-a-list-of-items-in-mvc)

At some point here you may want to actually consider using a **grid control**, but I'm not trying to plug Telerik or DevExpress controls.  So, instead I'll mention the following that came up in my search.  Perhaps other users can suggest other controls.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720348/MVC-Grid-Inline-Edit

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165410/ASP-NET-MVC-Editable-DataTable-jQuery-DataTables-a