# MVC How can I dynamicaly add input fields to a view model

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I have a form that uses the following viewmodel

```
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public List<LotViewModel> Lots { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Number of Lots")]
        public int NumberOfFields { get; set; }
    }
```

NumberOfFields is used in a for loop to render LotViewModels. The user selects a number from 1 -> 4 from a drop down. There is a JS function that then uses AJAX that calls a Controller method to render a partial view containing the correct number of fields. This JS function is triggered when the drop down changes.

This is the controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddLotFields(int numberOfFields)
{
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel
    {
        Lots = new List<LotViewModel>(),
        NumberOfFields = numberOfFields
    };
    return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/MainController/_LotForm.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

And this is the Javascript

```
$(function() {
$("#numberOfLotsDD").change(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.g_baseUrl + "MainController/AddLotFields/",
        data: {
            numberOfFields: $(this).val()
        },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",

        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $("#LotFields").html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

This works fine but when you submit the form the viewModel doesn't contain any elements in Lots.

The partial view that renders the input fields is

```
@model MainViewModel

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.NumberOfFields; i++)
{
    Model.Lots.Add(new LotViewModel());
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lots.Last().BatchIdLocation)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Lots.Last().BatchIdLocation, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Batch Id tag" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lots.Last().BatchIdLocation)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Lots.Last().QuantityLocation)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Lots.Last().QuantityLocation, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Quantity tag" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Lots.Last().QuantityLocation)
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
}
```

I've messed around with a few ways of trying to save this form but none of it has worked.

I know if I'm really stuck I could use JQuery to send the form input values to my controller. But I would like to avoid that if possible and keep the solution confined to c# and razor

Comment: Your partial view is not rendering the correct names to be able to submit them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I post a list of items in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321736/how-can-i-post-a-list-of-items-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field names need to be in the form of `Lots[N].PropertyName`, but your field names are being generated as just `PropertyName`.

Instead of using `model.Lots.Last()`, use the actual index, i.e. `model.Lots[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion - You can create the items in your collection at server side itselft instead of passing a flag to view to generate numbers of items.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddLotFields(int numberOfFields)
{
    var lots = new List<LotViewModel>();
    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfFields; index++)
    {
        lots.Add(new LotViewModel());
    }

    return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/MainController/_LotForm.cshtml", lots);
}
```

This will also give you ability to initialize the view model properties with external factor dependent values.

So the changes in view would be as follows :

```
@model List<LotViewModel>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lots[i].BatchIdLocation)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Lots[i].BatchIdLocation, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Batch Id tag" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lots[i].BatchIdLocation)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lots[i].QuantityLocation)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Lots[i].QuantityLocation, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Quantity tag" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lots[i].QuantityLocation)
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
}
```

The above change will also create the appropriate name at html for each field so that at form post, data post appropriately.