# How to pass a complex model back to the controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

New to web development.
I have a view that allows user to select an excel file.
When submit "preview" button is pressed file is read and data is sent back to the user to preview the data. 
Then I want to be able send the model back to the control for db upload.
(this is the part I'm struggling with).

ViewModel:

```
public class UploadItemsViewModel
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase upload { get; set; }

    public UploadJournalsViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection, int CompanyID)
    {
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
            }
        }
        UploadItemsViewModel itmViewModel = new UploadItemsViewModel { Company = db.Companies.Find(CompanyID), CompanyID = CompanyID };
        return View(itmViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(UploadItemsViewModel itmViewModel, string Preview, string Upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (itmViewModel.upload != null && itmViewModel.upload.ContentLength >0)
            {
                try
                {
                    itmlViewModel.Items = App.Services.ItemsMassUploadFileRead.ReadExcelFile(itmViewModel.upload, db.Companies.Find(itmViewModel.CompanyID));

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preview))
                    {
                        foreach (var itm in itmViewModel.Items)
                        {
                            itm.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
                            itm.CompanyID = itmViewModel.CompanyID;
                            itm.User = null;
                            itm.Items.Add(itm);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        return View();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View(itmViewModel);
                    }

                   }                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", ex.Message.ToString());
                    return View(itmViewModel);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file");
            }
        }
        return View(itmViewModel);
    }
```

View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ItemsUpload", null, FormMethod.Post,  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

{@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyID)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-default">
                Browse&hellip; <input type="file" style="display: none;" accept=".xlsx" name="upload">
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control " readonly>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block">
        Please use a provided Excel template
    </span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Preview" name ="Preview" class="btn btn-default" disabled style="display: none" id="submit"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Upload" class="btn btn-default" id="Upload" />
</div>

<div class="help-block" id="previewHelp" style="display: none">
    Preview results and scroll down to upload data to the database.
</div>



if (Model.Journals.Count != 0)
{
  table here to preview the upload
}
```

After clicking the Upload button model comes back without the "items" collection.

Comment: You have to render `<input/>` elements for all data you want to post back. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16321736/1450855 on how to POST lists correctly so the MVC modelbinder unterstands them.

Comment: Thanks. Managed to solve the issue using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Items` list will be always `null` in the controller, because you don't rendered any input on the View with the name `Items`